# NPM, Bower, Yo commands not working in Webstorm but do work in Terminal

Tags: npm, bower, yeoman, webstorm

Not sure if this is the right place to ask but I can't find anything online.  I have installed Yeoman on my computer and the command yo works in my terminal.  It wont however work in the terminal in Webstorm.  It says the command is not found.  Same with NPM and Bower.  Anyone have any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: What OS are you on? Try running WebStorm from your terminal - does the problem persist?

Comment: @lena I'm on Yosemite and I'm not sure how to run webstorm from terminal.

Comment: Something like `open  -a /Applications/WebStorm.app/` (from [this thread](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/452524?tstart=30))

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks that did open it! It still isn't running any commands EG. npm, yo ect.

Comment: @LandonCall Don't know then -- in all cases which I was aware this trick helped.